# How to run basic R raster operations in parallel?

Tags: r, raster, parallel-foreach

I have these example rasters:

```
s <- stack(replicate(10, {raster(matrix(runif(2160*4320), 2160),
xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)}))

s2 <- stack(replicate(10, {raster(matrix(runif(2160*4320), 2160), 
xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)}))

r <- raster(nrow=3000, ncol=7200, ymn=-60, ymx=90) 
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
```

I want to be able to use multi cores to run R and Raster basic functions such as:

```
s * s2
resample(s, r)
```

Comment: Have a look, for example, [here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/raster/html/cluster.html) (for documentation of **raster**'s native support for parallel processing) and [here](http://publish.illinois.edu/jgrn/software-and-datasets/rasterengine-tutorial/) (for a tutorial on `rasterEngine()`, from the **spatial.tools** package).

Comment: See package `parallel`: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf

Comment: Those method require that you put the argument in a function. Is there any way to avoid having funtions?

Comment: Well, the first link I left for you does mention that, for `resample`, use of the cluster is automatic. Other than that, yeah, you may need to put the argument in a function, which should be well worth doing if you really need the speedup you'll get by moving to parallel processing.

Comment: with only using one core for the re-sampling part I get these numbers:
`user  system elapsed 
99.63   32.64  134.78` with multicore using raster defaults after 20 minutes it is still working!

Comment: Look at `gdalUtils::gdalwarp` for resampling. It can be much faster. e.g. `writeRaster(s, paste0(tempdir(), '/', LETTERS[1:10], '.tif'), bylayer=TRUE); sapply(LETTERS[1:10], function(x) gdalwarp(sprintf('%s/%s.tif', tempdir(), x), sprintf('%s/%s_resamp.tif', tempdir(), x), te=c(bbox(r)), tr=res(r)))` - the resampling here takes ~40 sec on my system.

Comment: @jbaums does gdalwarp let you keep the files as stack? I need to run several other functions on these files and I want to keep them as stack. How other simple functions like multiplication work under this library?

Comment: Your `s*s2` is pretty quick with `raster`(~15 seconds for me). `gdalUtils` doesn't have an interface to gdal_calc, which is what you'd use to multiply grids with GDAL, but you could call [`gdal_calc.py`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) with `system` (for example). I have an example of simple masking using gdal_calc at https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/ab0214cefa30e2c62f23.

Comment: `gdalwarp` operates on source files, not on `Raster*` objects, but you can have it return a stack for you if you want - see the `output_Raster` argument at `?gdalUtils::gdalwarp`.

Comment: @jbaums would you put this in the answer section for the above examples?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I'm using the latest version of raster and all processes using ClusterR are significantly slower than using the single core. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, but no, I don't. I haven't actually used ClusterR. Like @jbaums, though, I've realized sometimes substantial speedups by using gdalUtils.

Comment: @jbaums may I know what system are you using? I use Rstudio in windows 10 on a Xenon processor but my hard drive is regular with 7200rpm.

Comment: I'm running Win 8.1, 64-bit R (RStudio) on an i7-4770 with DDR3-1600 RAM. The HDD is a Samsung solid state drive.

Comment: @jbaums thanks! I think SSD drive is important here.